# Slicing gives incorrect results if the values are the same

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to make a slice of a tensor with the same value.

```
import torch
dist = torch.ones((10, 20), dtype=torch.int32)
print(dist[[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

It returns `tensor([1, 1], dtype=torch.int32)`. But it should return `tensor([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=torch.int32)`. How do I make it to return this result?

Comment: Your result is equivalent to `[dist[1,3], dist[2,4]]`. It seems like what you want is `dist[1:3, 3:5]`?

Comment: @jodag, yes, exactly

Comment: *"yes, exactly"* Is that it, or are you trying to do something more?

Comment: @ivan, it's enough for my current problem